# WinApi: Give keyboard focus to new window in new thread

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, focus, accessibility

I have a dll that is called by a browser plugin when a user presses a button on a webpage. This dll contains native code which creates a window (in a new UI thread), and I need this window to gain keyboard focus on its creation (behavior expected by the user). I am not trying to shove an unwanted popup in the user's face.

I have tried to use SetForegroundWindow(), SetFocus(), BringWindowToTop(), AttachThreadInput(), minimizing/restoring the window, you name it, I've tried it. The most progress I've made is getting the new window to flash in the taskbar.

The reason I need to be able to do this is because I need to account for keyboard accessibility, and allow users to use my new window without having to alt-tab to it.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get keyboard focus here?

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that IE runs as a low-integrity process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the window is flashing on the taskbar then your code does not meet the requirements outlined in the [`SetForegroundWindow()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx):

> A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> The process is the foreground process.
>
> The process was started by the foreground process.
>
> The process received the last input event.
>
> There is no foreground process.
>
> The foreground process is being debugged.
>
> The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
>
> The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
>
> No menus are active.
>
> **An application cannot force a window to the foreground
>   while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows
>   flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user.**